# How to get "GET" response in Python as array?

Tags: python, get

I get response as text:

```py
import requests as req
url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/derivatives'
resp = req.get(url)
print(resp.text) # Printing response
```

Example:
[image: Example]

I want variable as array with same data.
Like an
array = resp.text
And then i can:
array[0]['market'] and get Deepcoint(Deriatives) output

Comment: pls elaborate more,

Comment: Exactly the same answer as I get now in the picture, just that it is not in text format but in an array format. So that I can work with this data

Comment: Like an 
array = resp.text
And then i can:
array[0]['market'] and get Deepcoint(Deriatives) output

Comment: You're looking for `resp.json()`

Comment: resp = req.json(url)
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'json'

Answer (score 0):

json will resolve your problem

```
import requests as req
import json
url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/derivatives'
```

`json.loads` will parse the data into list of dictionaries

```
resp = json.loads(req.get(url).text)
```

Now you can access the list of dictionary according to your need

```
print(resp[0]['market'])
```

will give you `'Deepcoin (Derivatives)'`

Comment: No need for the *json* module here. Just call the *json()* function on the response from *requests.get()* after validating the HTTP status code